# Setting a jQuery dialog button callback

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, callback

Hey coders, i would like to initialize a dialog box with a callback function for say a 'save' button but i want the callback to reside as a standalone function rather than defined inline using function(){....} the code snippet below highlights what I want to do.

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": saveAction() 
...
function saveAction()  
{  
}
```

what is the proper syntax for the "Save": saveAction() line cause it is doesn't seem to work?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parens after `saveAction` makes the function execute. Use this instead:

```
        "Save": saveAction
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks moff. what if I need to pass some parameters to the function? how can i do that?

Comment: If you need to pass parameters to that function you'll want to call it from an anonymous function e.g. `"Save": function() { saveAction(a,b) })`

Answer (score 0):

saveAction must have parameters defined in the signature: i.e. saveAction(a,b,c), then when setting the callback do this:

```
"Save": saveAction({a = "val", b = "val", c = "val"})
```

Comment: getting syntax error. say i only need to pass one parameter: this is what I have: function saveAction(save_context){ dosomething }; so to set up the callback should i do this "Save": saveAction({context}) or "Save": saveAction({save_context = context})? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass in parameters, you must wrap your function call in an anonymous function definition, like this:

```
"Save": function() { saveAction({a = "val", b = "val", c = "val"}) }
```

This effectively defines a new anonymous function that takes no parameters, and which when executed will call your own function with your desired paramters.